# How to generate track changes from files before and after changes are made?

Tags: ms-word

I have two versions of a word document as two different files.
How can I get a track changed version?
Is there a way to compare them and merge as track changed version of these two documents?

PS: MS Word's comparing tool seems a solution it doesn't work for me. I need its "track changes" version.

Answer (score 0):

First, turn on Track Changing

On the Review tab, in the Tracking group, click the Track Changes image.

To add a track changes indicator to the status bar, right-click the status bar and click Track Changes. Click the Track Changes indicator on the status bar to turn Track Changes on or off.

NOTE   If the Track Changes command is unavailable, you might have to turn off document protection. On the Review tab, in the Protect group, click Protect Document, and then click Stop Protection at the bottom of the Protect Document task pane. (You might need to know the document password.)

NOW,

On the Tools menu, click Track Changes.
When the Track Changes feature is enabled, TRK appears on the status bar at the bottom of your document. When you turn off change tracking, TRK is dimmed.

Make the changes you want by inserting, deleting, or moving text or graphics. You can also change formatting.

Track changes while you edit

You can easily make and view tracked changes and comments while you work in a document. By default, Microsoft Office Word 2007 uses balloons to display deletions, comments, formatting changes, and content that has moved. If you want to see all of your changes inline, you can change settings so that tracked changes and comments display the way you want.

Balloons show formatting changes, comments, and deletions.
 NOTE   To prevent you from inadvertently distributing documents that contain tracked changes and comments, Word displays tracked changes and comments by default. Final Showing Markup is the default option in the Display for Review box.

**Track changes while you edit**

Open the document that you want to revise.
On the Review tab, in the Tracking group, click the Track Changes image.
To add a track changes indicator to the status bar, right-click the status bar and click Track Changes. Click the Track Changes indicator on the status bar to turn track changes on or off.
Make the changes that you want by inserting, deleting, moving, or formatting text or graphics. You can also add comments.